# How to set Field value using id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set an HTML field's value using JavaScript when `onclick` event is raised by clicking a button/hyperlink.. I Googled and found many articles using the `name` attribute, but I want to set the value using the field's `id` only.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) .. The concept is the same as using name, a simple trial and error answer...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('Id').value='new value';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: In  my opinion just the fact that w3schools charges money to issue certificates that no employers are likely to recognise is reason enough to avoid them. Also the actual name "w3schools" seems like a cynical attempt to trick people into thinking they have some association with the w3c when they really don't, so that's another reason to steer clear.

Comment: @Jayantha: the others are right, linking W3Schools as a reference is really bad. Please change your link to MDN (Mozilla's Developer Network): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById. Thanks!

Comment: Ok got it, I will change. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Do i need to refresh it after set the value ... it didnt reflect on the UI

Comment: @sparsh610, no you don't need to refresh it should reflect immediately. If you refresh the browser it will be gone again.

Comment: @sk8erPeter - Whether you "like" the linked site or not should be irrelevant if it contained a proper reference to the questioned asked. It was a valid reference. They might sell irrelevant certs, but so do hundreds of other people. They provide a free reference that helped answer the question fine. The pettiness of SO at times is delicious.

Comment: @Mattt: W3Schools has improved very much since the old times of W3Fools ([see this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110117085131/http://w3fools.com/) for example) and since I wrote my comment (like others did). But back then, W3Schools had very poor quality, issued worthless certificates, and was not willing to declare that they have nothing to do with the offical W3C organization, these are facts. So calling "pettiness" that we mentioned these facts is very unfair, I hope you just didn't find better words to describe your resentment.

Comment: @sk8erPeter Thanks for the response. Honestly, it's hard to call personal opinion "fact" even when you fee it is warranted. I remember W3C stuff back in the day, yes, some of it was very silly. I don't though  remember the references to things like getElementById being wrong. So, while what you and others commented may have been true, it really had no effect on the answer. You didn't force any additional knowledge aside from your dislike for W3C. In my book, that fits the definition of petty. It was really a knock on the inconsistency of SO and it's feigned outrage. Just having fun :)